# Let-s-Encrypt( certbot) Не получается настроить

Tags: nginx, ssl, letsencrypt

Использую Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS и nginx

Потребовалось применить certbot и установить сертификат

Поначалу я установил сам certbot, далее указал в nginx конфиге

```
location ~ /.well-known {
    allow all;
}
```

Сделал регистрацию почты

Есть домен вида `sitename.ninja`, а так же джанго проект, который лежит по пути `/home/site/djangoproject/`

Пытаюсь сделать проверку, все ли работает корректно

```
certbot certonly --dry-run -a webroot --webroot-path=/home/site/djangoproject -d sitename.ninja -d sitename.ninja
```

В итоге получаю вот такое

```
   Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator webroot, Installer None
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): acme-staging.api.letsencrypt.org
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for sitename.ninja
Using the webroot path /home/site/djangoproject for all unmatched domains.
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Failed authorization procedure. sitename.ninja (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://sitename.ninja/.well-known/acme-challenge/oBBe03rmZYyaaZGJEnkpQJq2BOLw4: "<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>"

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: sitename.ninja
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://sitename.ninja/.well-known/acme-challenge/oaZGJumoOXm89Nd1tQJEnkpQJq2BOLw4:
   "<html>
   <head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
   <body bgcolor="white">
   <center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
   <hr><center>"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

Подскажите, в чем проблема?

Вот сама команда, с которой я брал пример

```
certbot certonly --dry-run -a webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/test/public -d test.com -d www.test.com
```

При попытке перейти по `http://sitename.ninja/.well-known/acme-challenge/oaZGJumoOXm89Nd1tQJEnkpQJq2BOLw4` я получаю 404 Not Found

Но по какой причине? Не могу понять

Comment: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/404-on-well-known-acme-challenge/15565/12

Comment: Настройте [location well-known/acme-challenge](https://habrahabr.ru/post/279695/)